# How to enter thése chàràctèrs into arbitrary programs?

Tags: windows-7, windows, unicode, input-languages

Is there any way to allow the classic "Ctrl-Apostrophe-E"-style combos, which input accented characters, work in *any* text box, rather than just in special programs like Wordpad or Microsoft Word?

Answer (score 3):

[Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) is always the answer.

http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic570.html

This script will allow you to enter a variety of characters in **any** program.

It's a long script to cut and past into the answer so I'll hold off.  Basically, it allows you to use the same Microsoft Word hotkeys in any program.

Comment: Wow, no built-in solution in Windows? +1 for Autohotkey then, I guess that's a possible choice too.

Comment: @Mehrdad: IMO, Microsoft's position is understandable. Not all programs accept accent characters the same way. Some don't at all, so forcing them could introduce more bugs.

Comment: And for Linux there's AutoKey.

Answer (score 2):

Open the **Control Panel**, **Region and Language**, **Keybaords and Languages**, **Change keyboards...**
Press **Add**.  Select your language, and select **Keyboard**.
Tick **Show More...**  Find and tick **United States-International**.  Press **OK**.
Optionally, change the **Default input language** to your new keyboard.  Press **OK**.
Press **OK** once more.

Now you should have a keyboard icon next to your system tray in the task bar.  You can turn the feature on and off here.  Now you can type any of these symbols, by typing punctuation before the letter.  Capital letters work too.

```
' + c, e, y, u, i, o, a = ç, é, ý, ú, í, ó, á  
" + e, y, u, i, o, a    = ë, ÿ, ü, ï, ö, ä 
` + e, u, i, o, a       = è, ù, ì, ò, à 
~ + o, n, a             = õ, ñ, ã 
^ + e, u, i, o, a       = ê, û, î, ô, â
```

Comment: These don't seem to work for me. What's the exact key combo? Did I miss a step? I tried Ctrl-` followed by e but didn't get è.

Comment: You don't press Ctrl.  You just press punctuation, letter, one after the other.  For example: typing 'e gives é.  Think of it as typing smileys in a chat program.  You just type :) and you get a smiley.  Do you see a keyboard icon next to the system tray?  When you click it, are there the options "US" and "United States-International"?

Comment: Oooh that's interesting. How do I type the symbol by itself though? Do I have to do `T-H-A-T-'-<space>-S` just to type in `that's` every time?

Comment: Only if the following character joins with the accent.  Typing **'s** will show **'s** because there are no accents on s.  The only word I can think of that will give you trouble is ma'am.  Of course you'll need to watch out with "every" quoted string starting with a vowel.

Comment: But what about when I want to type a `\`` in something like the box here? There are more situations than contractions.

Comment: Then switch to the US keyboard.  Frankly this site is an exception.  How often do you use ` outside of this site?  You can always hit space after the punctuation mark.  It's designed to be used by people who type 50 words-per-minute in a different language, so using modifiers like Ctrl would slow them down.  I, coming from an English background, would just have to learn to hit space after certain keys.

Comment: Hahaha ok, +1 for mentioning this; I had no idea what the international keyboard did until now! (BTW, I use the `^` and `~` and and `"` symbols very often when programming... `~nextValue` or `"End of file"` and stuff like that is quite typical.)

Answer (score 1):

The Character Map program will let you do it in most text fields.  <kbd>win</kbd>, type `charmap`

It can also be found in Accessories/System Tools

Comment: -1 how is this related to the key combo?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I save all the non-ascii chars I use frequently to a single text file - and copy/paste from there.